# Goroutine with sync.waitGroup output different value each time

Tags: go, goroutine

Code below will print different values each time after execution, but I want the values to be same, how to change the code below without using `time.Sleep`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var total int
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// Inc increments the counter for the given key.
func inc(num int) {
    total += num
    wg.Done()
}

// Value returns the current value of the counter for the given key.
func getValue() int {
    return total
}

func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go inc(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(getValue())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a data race, and the outcome is undefined. You have to synchronize the access to the share variable:

```
var total int
var lock sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// Inc increments the counter for the given key.
func inc(num int) {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    total += num
    wg.Done()
}

// Value returns the current value of the counter for the given key.
func getValue() int {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    return total
}
```

Or, use `sync/atomic` to access/modify the variable.

Comment: Hi, is it necessary to using sync.lock inside `getValue`? As it's not inside goroutine and it's been called after the wg.Wait() function

Comment: It is in a goroutine, the one running `main()`. However, `wg.Wait` does establish a happened-before relationship, so as long as `getValue` call is the only instance of that call, it should work without a lock. I wonder if the race detector sees it as a race, though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got different value each time is the race condition in `total += num`.

One simple fix is adding a mutex:
`var mu sync.Mutex`

And use it in `inc` :

```
func inc(num int) {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    total += num
    wg.Done()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already mentioned that you have "data race", and using `Mutex` is a solution. Alternatively you can use `atomic` package, which is faster.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var total uint64
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func inc(num uint64) {
    atomic.AddUint64(&total, 1)
    wg.Done()
}

// Value returns the current value of the counter for the given key.
func getValue() uint64 {
    return atomic.LoadUint64(&total)
}

func main() {
    for i := uint64(1); i <= 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go inc(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(getValue())
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Is AddUint64 for some reason, or AddUint32 is also ok to use?
What's the performance between atomic and mutex.

Comment: @eason, use `AddUint32()` if `uint32` fits your needs. Perfomance depends on many factors. On my PC bench like this https://play.golang.org/p/Do9mTKX4ExV shows 6 vs 16 ns/op

Comment: Is it related to my os 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: @eason Using `uint64` on win32 is ok and vice versa